# Ant design confirm modal is not closing on click of Yes and No

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I'm using Ant design, But Modal is not closing as expected on click of Yes and No. Can Some one help here is the code

```
function Study(props) {
let data=props.data
   const showConfirm=(e,val,view) =>{ debugger
  confirm({
    title: 'Are you sure you want to remove '+val+' from your study list?',
    icon: <ExclamationCircleOutlined />,
    okText: 'Yes',
    cancelText: 'No',
    onOk:()=>{confirmOk(val,view)},
    onCancel() {
      console.log('Cancel');
    },
  });
}
 return (
    <div>
      {props.deleteOption && <img  class="deleteIcon" src={crossIcon}   onClick={(e)=>showConfirm(e,data.studyName,props.view)}></img>}
   </div>
 )

}
```

Please some one suggest the solution

Comment: Can Someone please suggest the solution? I'm Stuked on this.

Answer (score 0):

you just reduce the vue version and remove ^ icon in json its stop the vue update itself

do these things it would be work sure

[click to view my json file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cCey5.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

onOk    Specify a function that will be called when the user clicks the OK button. The parameter of this function is a function whose execution should include closing the dialog. If the function does not take any parameter (!onOk.length) then modal dialog will be closed unless returned value is true (!!onOk()). You can also just return a promise and when the promise is resolved, the modal dialog will also be closed.

```
modal.confirm(
  {
    title: 'Xác nhận xóa',
    content: 'Bạn chắc chắn muốn xóa đối tượng có id là ' + entityId,
    onOk: (close) => {
      close()
    },
    maskClosable: true,
  }
);
```

Answer (score -1):

The Modal.method() usage: https://ant.design/components/modal#modalmethod

> All the Modal.methods will return a reference, and then we can update and close the modal dialog by the reference.

[image]

Comment: extremely unhelpful to post a screen grab of code (It can't be searched/indexed, copied etc)

Comment: @JohnCogan Unfortunately I paste url has beed changed to https://ant.design/components/modal#modalmethod After all, almost three years have passed.

Comment: Use text not images if you are showing code please